# promise { <pending> } using async await

Tags: javascript, node.js

trying to understan promises... I have this

```
async function fetchUsers(idUser) {
    const result = await User.forge({id: idUser}).fetch({columns:['name']});
    return result
}

router.get('/users', (req, res) => {
    const userData = {
        iduser: req.userId,
    }

    Orders.getOrders(userData, (err, rows) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }

        let user = fetchUsers(req.userId);
        console.log(user)
        console.log('-------------------------------');
        console.log(rows)
        res.json({orders: rows});
    });             
});
```

And I´m getting promise {  } in the `console.log(user)`. Shouldn´t this work with async/await or I am using it wrong?

Comment: `fetchUsers` returns a `Promise`, if you want the value it resolves to, use `await` or call `.then` on it

Comment: `await` doesn't stop the world. The `fetchUsers` function still is asynchronous.